# won't update from Preferences

Tags: android, preferences

It updates front activity when I edit or just click ok on any input in preferences screen and than i must first hide front activity. It gives me zero on button and in preferences xml i gave right key and also defaultValue.

So .. scenario: i go to preferences screen, click to edit button text, just click ok, go back, its "0" on button, hide front activity, go back to front activity and theres is the right value.

I hope i included all necessary parts.

```
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private static final int MENU_PREFERENCES = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int SHOW_PREFERENCES = 1;

    private void updateFromPreferences() {
       mobileNumber = prefs.getString("mobileNumber", "0");
    }

    private void refreshAplication(){
       button.setText(mobileNumber);
    }

    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       updateFromPreferences();
       refreshAplication();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (MENU_PREFERENCES): {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_PREFERENCES);
            return true;
        }
       }
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == SHOW_PREFERENCES)
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        updateFromPreferences();
        refreshAplication();
      } 
    }

    public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreferences);
      }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `refreshAplication();` in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be following this :

[example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)